# C#: Interface and Abstract to enable Implement and Override

Tags: c#, interface, overriding, implementation, abstract

I've got to design about 5 different classes.

A lot of the parts of these classes will be very similar, but they will have slight differences (of course).

If I write an `interface` that each of my designed classes implement, then each `abstract` method in the `interface` has to be completely written.

If I write a `base` class that each of my designed classes derives from, then each class will automatically have some functionality in the `virtual` method that I create in the `base` class, but they would all need to be overridden, calling the `base` functionality, to include the slight differences.

Is there a way to combine these features? I like requiring the `interface`'s methods to be implemented, but I also like having set features pre-programmed by a `base` class.

I've looked at many examples here and elsewhere, but it does not look like anyone does what I am describing. Is it even possible?

**EDIT:** So, given this:

```
abstract class Base
{
    virtual protected void OptionallyOverridable() {}
    abstract protected void SubclassMustImplement();
}
```

...is there a way to write something that does like this:

```
abstract class Base2
{
    DataEventType EventType;
    DataChangedEventHandler OnDataChange;

    virtual protected void OptionallyOverridable() {}
    abstract protected void SubclassMustImplement() {
      // values here are guaranteed
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for in the edit

Comment: For all of these similar classes to behave the same, they need to all implement certain features (namely my custom events).

Comment: Just put those events on your interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AllenG got my plus one, but since I had already typed this out, here is a lengthier and more explicit demonstration of the concept...

Define your interface...

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoIt();
    void DoItWithoutDefaultBehavior();
}
```

Define a base class that implements the interface with some default behaviors, or perhaps some methods don't have a default behavior...

```
public abstract class BaseFoo : IFoo
{
    public virtual void DoIt()
    {
         // Base behavior
         Console.WriteLine("base");
    }

    // This one has no base behavior
    public abstract void DoItWithoutDefaultBehavior();
}
```

Some of your subclasses might use those default behaviors ...

```
public class DerivedFoo1 : BaseFoo, IFoo
{
    // Doesn't override DoIt, takes BaseFoo

    public override void DoItWithoutDefaultBehavior()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo1");
    }
}
```

Others might add to them ...

```
public class DerivedFoo2 : BaseFoo, IFoo
{
    public override void DoIt()
    {
        base.DoIt();
        // Additional stuff
        Console.WriteLine("derived");
    }

    public override void DoItWithoutDefaultBehavior()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo2");
    }
}
```

You can call the methods through the class or the interface.

```
void Main()
{
    var foo1 = new DerivedFoo1();
    foo1.DoIt();

    var foo2 = new DerivedFoo2();
    foo2.DoIt();

    IFoo foo1AsFoo = new DerivedFoo1();
    foo1AsFoo.DoIt();

    IFoo foo2AsFoo = new DerivedFoo2();
    foo2AsFoo.DoIt();
}
```

See also: [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx) which discusses whether `DerivedFoo1` and `DerivedFoo2` should restate that they implement `IFoo` when `BaseFoo` already says so. They do in my example for the sake of being explicit.

**EDIT**
It's definitely possible to add events to the interface. I made the following changes to my example. You could make similar changes:

- To `interface IFoo`, add `event EventHandler TheEvent;`
- To `BaseFoo`, add `public event EventHandler TheEvent;`
- To `BaseFoo.DoIt`, add `if (TheEvent != null)
  {
      var args = new EventArgs();
       TheEvent(this, args);
  }`
- Add `public void TheHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("Fired.");
  }`
- To `Main`, add `foo1.TheEvent += TheHandler;`

The output now becomes

```
base
Fired.
base
derived
base
base
derived
```

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. I was thinking I might have to implement the interface in a base class and somehow work that out to the derived class. I'll need to turn away from the monitor and meditate on this for a few minutes. It looks like it does not do quite what I wanted.

Comment: FYI: I also saw AllenG's version, but wasn't sure where to go with it. Thanks for the lengthier explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to add EVENTS to your interface? I've tried on my side, but for some reason these events are not accessible or visible in my derived class. I'm doing something wrong, I'm sure.

Answer (score 5):

C# allows a class to both inherit from a base class and implement an interface, so why not just do both?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public void Bar();
    public bool Baz();
}

public abstract class BaseFoo : IFoo
{
    //fields/properties used in all classes
    public void Bar()
    { //Implementation }

    public bool Baz()
    { //Implementation }
}

public class DerivedFoo : BaseFoo, IFoo {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and you already answered yourself. You will do both:

- Have a base class with basic implementation
- Have child classes (or base class, why not?) implement the interfaces you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix both interface and abstract, I think what you want is something like this

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void ImplementMe();
    int ImplementId { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseFoo : IFoo
{
    public virtual void ImplementMe()
    {
        CommonStuff();
    }

    public abstract int ImplementId { get; }

    private void CommonStuff()
    {
        // ... do stuff ?
    }
}

public sealed class FooImplementationA : BaseFoo
{
    public override int ImplementId { get { return 0; } }

    public override void ImplementMe()
    {
        MoreStuff();
        base.CommonStuff();
    }

    private void MoreStuff()
    {
        // ... do more stuff.
    }
}

public sealed class FooImplementationB : BaseFoo
{
    public override int ImplementId { get { return 1; } }

    public override void ImplementMe()
    {
        DifferentStuff();
        base.CommonStuff();
    }

    private void DifferentStuff()
    {
        // ... do different stuff.
    }
}
```

but then again you don't really *need* the interface and can simply get away with using the `BaseFoo` abstract class

Answer (score 0):

The 'abstract' keyword is what you are looking for.

```
    abstract class Base
    {
        virtual protected void SubclassCanCallAndOptionallyOverride() {}
        abstract protected void SubclassMustBeImplement();
    }
```

For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx

Comment: Almost all I need can be handled by the `interface`, but I would really like the classes that implement that `interface` to have some guaranteed custom types and values in them. Can this be done?